# Determine the radius of convergence of the following power series.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

**PROBLEM**

What is the radius of convergence of the following power series?

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\bigg(1 - e^{in\pi/4}\bigg)^n z^n}$$

**MY ATTEMPT**

Let $a_n = \bigg(1 - e^{in\pi/4}\bigg)^n$.

I shall use the Cauchy-Hadamard Formula for the radius of convergence $R$:

$$\frac{1}{R} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sup\left|a_n\right|^{1/n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sup\left|\bigg(1 - e^{in\pi/4}\bigg)^n\right|^{1/n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sup\left|1 - e^{in\pi/4}\right|$$

But
$$1 - e^{in\pi/4} = \begin{cases}
{\frac{\sqrt{2} - 1}{\sqrt{2}}-i\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg) \text{ , } n = 1 \\
1 - i \text{ , } n = 2 \\
\frac{\sqrt{2} + 1}{\sqrt{2}}-i\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg) \text{ , } n = 3 \\
2 \text{ , } n = 4 \\
\frac{\sqrt{2} + 1}{\sqrt{2}}+i\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg) \text{ , } n = 5 \\
1 + i \text{ , } n = 6 \\
\frac{\sqrt{2} - 1}{\sqrt{2}}+i\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg) \text{ , } n = 7 \\
0 \text{ , } n = 8 \\
}
\end{cases}$$

Clearly, $\sup\left|1 - e^{in\pi/4}\right| = 2$, so that
$$\frac{1}{R} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sup\left|1 - e^{in\pi/4}\right| = \lim_{n \to \infty}{2} = 2$$
from which we obtain
$$R = \frac{1}{2}.$$

**QUESTION**

> Is my solution to this problem correct?  If not, where is the error in my solution and how can it be mended?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, my $a_n$ takes the form $a_n = \bigg(1 - e^{in\pi/4}\bigg)^n$.

Comment: I see. Sorry. You are right. Looks good then.

Comment: It's correct. Just note the lim sup is obvious graphically=: the greatest distance between $1$ and a complex number with modulud $1$ is attained when this complex number is equal to $-1$.